# Get shipment Carrier in Amazon MWS?

Tags: amazon-mws

How to get a Carrier Name in Orders API of Amazon MWS for MFN Account which is already shipped? is it possible to do this using Order API?

Comment: I know how to get shipped orders but i'm not about carrier name, I have to read the documentation

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there currently is any API to retrieve tracking information (or even just the carrier name) through MWS.

For the sake of completeness: To *submit* shipping information including carrier names and tracking numbers, you can use the `SubmitFeed` API with FeedType=`_POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_`. The corresponding XSD (OrderFulfillment.xsd) defines the following values as valid `CarrierCode`s: USPS, UPS, FedEx, DHL, Fastway, GLS, GO!, Hermes Logistik Gruppe, Royal Mail, Parcelforce, City Link, TNT, Target, SagawaExpress, NipponExpress, YamatoTransport . All other carriers must use the `CarrierName` field.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm sure it's available in MWS, it would be much easier to use the carriers shipping number structure to determine the carrier.

IE...

Fedex can have  12 or 15 digit tracking numbers and the barcode can be 22 digits.

UPS has 1Z in front of their tracking.

USPS format is 20 digits (e.g. 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999), or a combination of 13 alphabetic and numeric characters, usually starting with 2 alphabets, following by 9 digits, and ending by "US" (e.g. EA 999 999 999 US

build regular expression to handle these easily.

Comment: I'm inclined to say that you didn't understand the question accurately. I think Bhuvan was searching for a (probably web service) API in order to query those tracking numbers.

Comment: Hi Trinimon, yes you are right. i am searching to query the tracking number and carrier name based on the Amazon order number but i am not able to get the data.